# MySQL and PHP: searching string which could have leading zero

Tags: mysql

I have a small asset/stock database for laptops and desktops. The standard format for the asset name is LAP (for laptop) hyphen and 7 numbers, for example LAP-1234567.

I have field stored this as a Varchar in an MySQL database.

The historic data I've been given has many lazy entries of just the asset number which can sometimes has leading zeros. Due to this when searching for a laptop, I have to use LIKE using just the number of the asset for example

```
SELECT * from asset_tracker WHERE asset_id like '%0060366'
```

However it seems MySQL doesn't like leading zeros in the search and it finds nothing.  Using LIKE '%60366' does find the entry but I need it to search with the leading zeros.

Thanks

Comment: If your data "sometimes" has leading zeroes, you don't have many options. You have to search for both scenarios. The easiest is to simply trim the leading zeores from your search key.  Another option is to search with a regex.

Comment: Try `SELECT * from asset_tracker WHERE asset_id like '0%'`

Comment: `%60366` should find a record with the `id` of `0060366` please add your PHP and the sample DB record that doesn't show that match.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: If `like '%0060366'` doesn’t find anything, but `LIKE '%60366'` does - then that simply means you _do not have_ a record where the content of that field ends with `0060366`.

Comment: _“but I need it to search with the leading zeros”_ - that doesn’t make sense; you can not expect to find data, if you search for a value that doesn’t exist in the data. Perhaps what you actually mean is that you want to find this record, if the user performing the search has entered `0060366` as a search term? Well then you could/should cut of the leading zeroes off, before you search.

Comment: If Like '%0060366' should work, then I suspect the "zeros" in the data aren't zeros then

Comment: @misorude I have to search for the leading zeros because if use LIKE '%60366' it will find computer with the number 0160366 0260366 etc etc

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that it doesn’t make sense to search with `like '%0060366'`, if you have no records that end with `0060366`. And again, you can’t have any, otherwise that query would have returned them already. If you disagree or think we are wrong, then please start by adding proper example data to your question.

Comment: I've just created a different table and like '%0060366' does work  There must be something wrong with the table it's imported in to (I cant understand what) or there's something wrong with the data, which is mostly likely.

Comment: Output the data and iterate over it. Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php to see what each character is.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the data imported from a CSV in notepad and there's all sorts of garbage in the data.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score -2):

Try this below code correct format.

```
SELECT * from asset_tracker WHERE asset_id like "%0060366%";
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? How does this help with **leading** zeros?

Comment: You must assign the asset_id data type as varchar OR Text. Then it's working

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How does this code do that? This is the same as the OPs except there is an additional trailing wildcard (and double quotes instead of single which makes no affect).